# How to become eligible on Facebook to let users share links from our app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an ember app where users can make content. We have made it so that they can share this with an public link to Twitter LinkedIn and Facebook.
Only the Facebook part doesn't work.

We've made a Facebook app of our application, added all details and made sure we send the right data with our API calls. But we have this message that we can't get rid off (in the picture below). I thought I could just test this in production and try tho share the link from our app so it would work. Is there anything obvious we are missing now?

[image: Facebook error message]

We're sending the object like this to facebook:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/'+ <facebookNameSpace>,
  'post', {
    object: {
      app_id: <facebookAppId>,
      url: <url>,
      title: <title,
      image: <image_url>,
      type: <type>,
      description: <description>
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: How are you sharing the content? Did you implement Facebook login and are you asking for any permissions? Have you tried doing what the message asks you for?

Comment: We are asking for the following login permissions: email, public_profile and user_friends. These are all approved by default. 

Yes i've tried that. But maybe my understanding of publishing this action is not right?

Comment: You can not publish via API without asking the user for permission to do that beforehand.

Comment: Yes, but when it's shared it pops up a new window that shows and asks permissions to do that on facebook.

Comment: You need to test your permissions and API calls it before submitting to Facebook for approval, with admins/developers/test users.

Comment: I've tried sharing what i want to share with this function with both and admin/developers account and a test user account. I thought this was the testing for the permissions and API calls.